# Converting from DOMNodeInserted (deprecated) to MutationObserver

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, mutation-observers

I'm trying to switch from using the deprecated DOMNodeInserted to MutationObserver.

Currently my script using **DOMNodeInserted** does the following:

1. Detects a new, dynamically-added DOM element
2. Searches within the new element for a `select` tag
3. If a `select` tag is found, it calls a function which acts upon the `select` (adds Select2).

My new script using **MutationObserver** detects the added node (step 1) successfully, but then fails to detect the `select` within the new node (step2).

I've distilled my problem down in this [Code Pen](http://codepen.io/awestmoreland/pen/qrOVpm).

Comment: Can you include `html` and `javascript` at Question?

Comment: 1) You forgot `subtree: true` it seems. 2) `.find` won't find the node itself if it's `select`. See [How to change the HTML content as it's loading on the page](//stackoverflow.com/a/39334319), also [Performance of MutationObserver to detect nodes in entire DOM](//stackoverflow.com/a/39332340)

Comment: That's it! `subtree` solved my problem, and `.find` seems to work from there on out. Nice!

Comment: `.find` works in your case only because the added node is a container with `select` node inside.